# How to group array in json php from database

Tags: php, mysql, json, angular

I have source code like this:

```
elseif($postjson['aksi']=='load_Kelas'){
  $data = array();
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM t_kelas_kuliah");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $data[] = array(
          'kd_kelas'    => $row['kd_kelas'],
          'kd_matkul'   => $row['kd_matkul'],
          'kd_dosen'    => $row['kd_dosen'],
          'waktu'       => $row['waktu'],
          'ruang'       => $row['ruang'],
          'hari'        => $row['hari'],
      );
  }
  if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'result'=>$data));
  else $result = json_encode(array('success'=>false));
  echo $result;
}
```

in ionic code

```
async loadKelas() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let body = {
        aksi: 'load_Kelas',
      };

      this.accsPrvds.postData(body, 'proses_api.php').subscribe((kelas: any) => {
          for (let kelaskuliah of kelas.result) {
              this.datakelas.push(kelaskuliah);
          }
          resolve(true);
          console.log(kelas);
      });
    });
  }
```

result console is

```
result: (2) […]
​​
0: {…}
​​​
hari: "Senin"    ​​​
kd_dosen: "SPK"
​kd_kelas: "A1157"
​​​kd_matkul: "IFKK1051"
​​​ruang: "B310"
​​​waktu: "09.30 - 12.00"
​​​<prototype>: Object { … }
​​1: {}
​​​hari: "Senin"
​​​kd_dosen: "SPK"
​​​kd_kelas: "A1158"
​​​kd_matkul: "IFKK1051"
​​​ruang: "B310"
​​​waktu: "12.00 - 14.30"
```

how to create array by category 'Hari' then I have output like this

```
Data = [
  {
    Hari : "Senin",
    Kuliah = [
     { kd_dosen: "SPK", kd_kelas: "A1157", kd_matkul: "IFKK1051", ruang: "B310", waktu: "09.30 - 12.00" },
     { kd_dosen: "SPK", kd_kelas: "A1157", kd_matkul: "IFKK1051", ruang: "B310", waktu: "09.30 - 12.00" }
    ]}
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
elseif($postjson['aksi']=='load_Kelas'){
  $data = array();
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM t_kelas_kuliah");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $data[] = array(
          'kd_kelas'    => $row['kd_kelas'],
          'kd_matkul'   => $row['kd_matkul'],
          'kd_dosen'    => $row['kd_dosen'],
          'waktu'       => $row['waktu'],
          'ruang'       => $row['ruang'],
          'hari'        => $row['hari'],
      );
  }
  if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'result'=>$data));
  else $result = json_encode(array('success'=>false));
  echo $result;
}
```

with this:

```
elseif($postjson['aksi']=='load_Kelas'){
  $temp = array();
  $data = array();
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM t_kelas_kuliah");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $temp[$row['hari']][] = array(
          'kd_kelas'    => $row['kd_kelas'],
          'kd_matkul'   => $row['kd_matkul'],
          'kd_dosen'    => $row['kd_dosen'],
          'waktu'       => $row['waktu'],
          'ruang'       => $row['ruang'],
          'hari'        => $row['hari'],
      );
  };
  foreach($temp as $key => $val){
      $data[] = array(
        "Hari" => $key,
        "Kuliah" => $val
      );
  };
  if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'result'=>$data));
  else $result = json_encode(array('success'=>false));
  echo $result;
}
```

Comment: thank u, but the next problem how to show that in html

Comment: are you using javascript for parsing the data?

Comment: you can change this `if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'result'=>$data));` to `if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'result'=>$data,'rawresult'=>$temp));` and call **rawresult** instead of **result** but the return size will double the result size

Comment: maybe, I do not really understand.

Comment: if you use ajax to parse it :
try :
`function(data){
newdata = array();
data.forEach(function(item,index){
newdata.push(item.Kuliah);
});
}`

Comment: maybe im not using ajax, see in ionic code on top, i create var datakelas = [] .. in loadkelas().. i push it. then in html ionic the code is *ngFor="let kelas of datakelas", before split by category. data show, but now, not show : img html code https://ibb.co/RpYD4vM

Comment: try to replace `this.datakelas.push(kelaskuliah);` to `this.datakelas.push(kelaskuliah.Kuliah);`

Comment: in console log that data show, but proble in html *ngFor="let kelas of datakelas", they wont show

Comment: try this: `for (let temp of kelas.result) {
              for (let kelaskuliah of temp.Kuliah) {
                 this.datakelas.push(kelaskuliah);
              }
          }` i think this will work